# How to pin transitive dependencies with setup.py in python?

Tags: python, packaging

[python3-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml/blob/master/setup.py) library has the following dependency mentioned in setup.py

```
install_requires=[
    'isodate>=0.5.0',
    'xmlsec>=0.6.0'
],
```

The [xmlsec](https://github.com/mehcode/python-xmlsec/blob/master/requirements.txt) library itself has a lxml dependency pinned like this.

```
lxml >= 3.0
```

This is placing me in an unfortunate situation.

I want to pin down the version of lxml used by python3-saml project.
I can fork python3-saml, but what should I do so that my forked version python3-xml installs `lxml==3.7.3`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the purpose of *setup.py*'s *install_requires*. It is used by package maintainers to specify the *compatible* dependency versions, not to "pin" versions. See [install_requires vs Requirements files](https://packaging.python.org/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/).

Note that the dependencies you see in the two *setup.py* files here are not "pinned", as they allow multiple versions. See [PEP 440 Version Specifiers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-specifiers).

## How to install specific versions

Use [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/) to manage the *installed* versions of packages and transitive dependencies.

```
$ pip install python3-saml lxml==3.7.3
```

Now we can see that the desired version is installed.

```
$ pip freeze
defusedxml==0.5.0
isodate==0.6.0
lxml==3.7.3
pkgconfig==1.2.2
python3-saml==1.3.0
six==1.11.0
xmlsec==1.3.3
```